# Are only intervals connected in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

What if I consider null set or singleton set as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, surely they are connected and so are they considered as intervals?

Comment: Yes, they are. You have $\{x\}=[x,x]$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and, e.g., $\emptyset=[1,0]$.

Comment: When writing interval, it is always written in a<x<b format with < being the poset, which is simply less than in R, so I thibk use of [1,0] is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is the best way to define an interval: $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an interval if $x\in A$ for all $\inf A<x<\sup A$, when of course the supremum and infimum might be infinite as well. It is easy to see that a singleton is an interval. (there are just no values of $x$ such that $\inf A<x<\sup A$ in that case, so it is trivially an interval).

And yes, a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected if and only if it is an interval.

Comment: Then what about empty set? From the definition which I have heard, first the set should be nonempty to become an interval

Comment: I guess it is a matter of definitions. I like the definition I wrote because it is a way to define a general interval-it can be open, closed, half open, bounded or unbounded. According to this definition the empty set is an interval as well.

Answer (score 0):

$(a,a)=\emptyset\,,\forall a$ and $[a,a]=\{a\}$, so sure, why not?

Comment: That's use of notation, what's definition of interval according to you?

Comment: An interval is just the set of points between any two points;  open or closed depending on whether it's inclusive or exclusive.   I don't see anything to stop you from considering the empty set and singletons as special cases.

Comment: Oh yeah, we also have half-open intervals.   You could always make your own definitions;  like Steve Smale, who won a Fields medal.